# Chat rate limit pluralization bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, plurals

Found this out [when trying to recite the alphabet in messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39411/alphabet-group).

When you hit the rate limit in chat, and there is 1 second<s>s</s> left, it says the incorrect form. It shouldn't be plural.

Example:

[image: Example]

Can this be fixed please?

Seriously, this is slightly irritating. I am not just posting this to point out how annoying plurals are.

Comment: In before plural [tweet](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/1165936105) answer. :P

Comment: Another way to fix this would be to increase the minimum timeout to 2 seconds. ;)

Comment: @AdamLear that... would work but isn't exactly what I had in mind. :P

Comment: *bludgeons with giant S*

Comment: @ArtOfCode ahaha! That is what my giant strikethrough shield is for! _deflects and nullifies_

Comment: You forgot to quote the 'bug' in the title, so your shield is weakened! ArtOfCode uses Bludgeon! It's super effective!

Comment: @ArtOfCode Riker uses "Hey, Jeff Atwood is behind you with a bigger S!"! It's super effective. Then ArtOfCode is hit in the head with a bigger S, actually from Jeff.

Comment: ArtOfCode uses Dodge!

Comment: Woot. I can swear I've seen this bug report at least twice before . . .

Comment: @Ph I searched around. Either it isn't tagged plurals, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: @RikerW [tag:plurals] -> [tag:misplaced-giant-s]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chat rate limit messages are now appropriately pluralized.

[image]